# How do I create a multiline bot response in Rasa Core?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Can anyone help how to get bot responses in multiple lines.
Also how to get bullets in the Bot responses. I tried with `>`, `*` , enter key and also. Nothing seem to work. Does Rasa response templates support HTML tags?

Comment: I removed the downvote because the question in object is absolutely right immo. Minor point: the description add inside a different subtopic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visualization of the message depends on the output channel which you are using. 
Hence, it should be possible to provide HTML tags in your bots answers as long as your output channel can then correctly render it. For a simple newline, please try adding a "\n" in your messages, e.g.:

```
utter_message:
  - text: "First line\nSecond line\Third line"
```

You can also have a multiline string in your yaml file which then results in a string containing newlines ([see here for examples](https://yaml-multiline.info/)). The block below is the same as the example above:

```
utter_message:
    - text: >
        First line
        Second line
        Third line
```

To include bullets, you could simply add the [unicode character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/browsertest.htm) of a bullet, e.g.:

```
utter_message:
    - text: >
        • First line
        • Second line
        • Third line
```

Answer (score 2):

I think newlines doesn't correspond to "multiple bot responses" (that I interpret with multiple boxes on a instant messaging/caht channel. It's so in Telegram, by example. So I fair @Tobias solution isn't definitive.

A solution to have separate box messages could be to split the original single utterance in a sequence of utterances to be inserted afterward in a "story" as described in this RASA forum reply: https://forum.rasa.com/t/split-utterances-templates-into-multiple-answers/1204/2?u=solyarisoftware

That's more a workaround but that's debatable from the conversational design perspective. Maybe I want different boxes not just for a text pretty printing with newlines, but to communicate different semantics.

For example, if the user say:

> Hello

The bot could reply answering the greet and also introducing a new question/prompt to let the dialog continue.
And that could deserves a new box, for a sequence of 2 boxes.

So bot reply could better be:

> Hello!
>
> ---
>
> How are you?